# Ubuntu 16.04 dualboot with Windows 10 won´t start up

Tags: dual-boot

After installing windows 10 as second partition I used EasyBCD2.3 to start ubuntu as well. After 1 week of working fine now none of the OS willt start. It says that

> BOOTMGR is missing

Should I reinstall both operating systems or is there any other solution?

Comment: It's BOOTMGR, not BOOTMNGR, right?

Comment: @MarkYisri Precisely

Comment: Bootmgr is one of the Windows BIOS boot files. It must be in the same partition as the BCD and that partition must be an NTFS primary partition with boot flag. Often a separate 100MB boot partition with main Windows install in another partition. But if you have newer UEFI Windows you should  not be using EasyBCD as it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

On the systerm. Long press on shift. if it give you a boot option then  try doing this step, if not then i m sorry.

Select Advanced recovery option

It will give some options like ****normal start****, grub ******  select the one with grub.... it update grub sometimes it ask password, give it. restart system.